# Binomial series sum of the form $\sum^{k}_{r=0}(-1)^r(2)^{k-r}\binom{20}{r}\binom{20-r}{20-k}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

the value of

$$2^k\binom{20}{0}\binom{20}{20-k}-2^{k-1}\binom{20}{1}\binom{19}{20-k}+2^{k-2}\binom{20}{2}\binom{18}{20-k} \cdots+ +(-1)^k\binom{20}{k}\binom{20-k}{20-k}$$

options:

$(a)\;\; 7$

$(b)\;\;8$

$(c)\;\; 10$

$(d)\;\; 20$

Attempt: $$\sum^{k}_{r=0}(-1)^r(2)^{k-r}\binom{20}{r}\binom{20-r}{20-k} = (2)^{k}\sum^{k}_{r=0}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^r\frac{20!}{r!\times (20-r)!}\cdot \frac{(20-r)!}{(20-k)!\times (k-r)!}$$

$$ = \frac{(20)!(2)^{k}}{(20-k)!(k)!}\sum^{k}_{r=0}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^r\frac{k!}{r!\cdot (k-r)!} = \frac{(20)!(2)^{k}}{(20-k)!(k)!}\sum^{k}_{r=0}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^r\binom{k}{r}$$

$$ = \frac{(20)!(2)^{k}}{(20-k)!(k)!}\times \frac{1}{2^k} = \binom{20}{k}$$

none of the options is match.

please help me solve it, thanks

Comment: Starting at *Attempt :*, everything looks correct to me and I got the same result.

Comment: From the given options, the value doesn't seem to depend on $k$. For example, take $k=0$, then the answer is $1$. Don't they have a NOTA (none of the above, shorthand picked from Indian election campaign) button?

Answer (score 3):

The only possibility is D with k=1 or 19.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{r = 0}^{k}\pars{-1}^{r}\,\pars{2}^{k - r}{20 \choose r}
{20 - r \choose 20 - k} =
\bracks{z^{k}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell}\bracks{2^{\ell}
\sum_{r = 0}^{\ell}\pars{-\,{1 \over 2}}^{r}{20 \choose r}
{20 - r \choose \ell - r}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{k}}\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-\,{1 \over 2}}^{r}
{20 \choose r}\bracks{
\sum_{\ell = r}^{\infty}{20 - r \choose \ell - r}\pars{2z}^{\ell}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{k}}\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-\,{1 \over 2}}^{r}
{20 \choose r}\bracks{
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{20 - r \choose \ell}\pars{2z}^{\ell + r}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{k}}\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-\,{1 \over 2}}^{r}
{20 \choose r}\pars{2z}^{r}\bracks{
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{20 - r \choose \ell}\pars{2z}^{\ell}} =
\bracks{z^{k}}\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}
{20 \choose r}\pars{-z}^{r}\pars{1 + 2z}^{20 - r}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{1 + 2z}^{20}\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}
{20 \choose r}\pars{-\,{z \over 1 + 2z}}^{r}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{1 + 2z}^{20}\pars{1 - {z \over 1 + 2z}}^{20} =
\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{1 + z}^{20} = \bbx{\ds{20 \choose k}}
\end{align}

Comment: Isn't this reproving an identity already proved in the question?

Comment: @Did I suspect that at the very beginning. I'll wait 24 four hours to delete it such that you can read this comment. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't delete this answer because it proves a identity which the OP used without any proof.

Comment: @navinstudent You're right. Basically, my answer is related to a $\texttt{Generating Function}$ while the OP performs a 'disentangling' of the binomial coefficients. Thanks.